# JParsec for version numbers

Tags: java, jparsec

I am trying to write a simple parser for version numbers using JParsec 3. The version numbers look like:

```
123
1.2.3
123.4
```

The rule is:

> Up to three non-negative integers, separated by `.`

I have a `Version` `class` with three factory methods:

```
Version.of(int major)
Version.of(int major, int minor)
Version.of(int major, int minor, int patch)
```

I would like to write a parser for versions of any of the three types.

Here is what I have so far:

```
static final Parser<Integer> integerParser = Scanners.INTEGER
        .map(x -> Integer.parseUnsignedInt(x));

static final Parser<Version> versionParser1 =
        integerParser.map(x -> Version.of(x));

static final Parser<Version> versionParser2 =
        Parsers.sequence(
                integerParser.followedBy(Scanners.isChar('.')), 
                integerParser)
                .map(x -> Version.of(x.get(0), x.get(1)));

static final Parser<Version> versionParser3 =
        Parsers.sequence(
                integerParser.followedBy(Scanners.isChar('.')),
                integerParser.followedBy(Scanners.isChar('.')), 
                integerParser)
                .map(x -> Version.of(x.get(0), x.get(1), x.get(2)));

public static final Parser<Version> versionParser =
    versionParser1.or(versionParser2).or(versionParser3);
```

This doesn't actually compile, because where I have `x.get(0)`, `x` is an `Integer`.

How should I be using JParsec here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Parsers.sequence(p1,p2,...,map)` functions instead. The `Parsers.sequence(p1...).map(f)` behaviour is to drop the output of all parsers but the last. Then combine all parsers using a different combinator than `or()` because it will fail if parsers consume input but do not succeed. A possible solution is

`public static final Parser<Version> versionParser =
    Parsers.longest(versionParser1, versionParser2, versionParser3);`

Comment: Thanks, `longest` was exactly what I was looking for.